# Change date format jquery

Tags: jquery

hi i have this format to my map markers and i want to change date format from yyyy-mm-dd to dd-mm-yyyy
can you help me

```
webbuMarkers.markerClickFunction = function(pic, latlng) {
  return function(e) {
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    e.returnValue = false;
    var postid = pic.estate_post_id; 
    var title = pic.estate_title;
    var url = pic.estate_link;
    var fileurl = pic.estate_photo;
    var fileurl2 = pic.estate_photo2;
    var fileurl3 = pic.estate_photo3;
    var fileurl4 = pic.estate_photo4;
    var fileurl5 = pic.estate_photo5;
    var estate_address = pic.estate_address;
    var estate_sdesc = pic.estate_sdesc;
    var estate_adresse = pic.estate_adresse;
    var estate_prix = pic.estate_prix;
    var estate_date = pic.estate_date;
    var estate_email = pic.estate_email;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
var mydate = new Date();
var date = mydate.getDate();
var month = mydate.getMonth()+1;
var year = mydate.getFullYear();
alert(date + "-" + month + "-" + year);
```

Plus to 1 getMonth() since it starts 0 index.

Comment: it's weird, I used mozilla to test this out. Have you tried firebug and see the error?

Answer (score 0):

You can use date.js to achieve this:

```
var date = new Date('2014-12-04');
var newDate = date.toString('dd-MM-yy');
```

or u can use this also

```
var parts = fecha2.value.split('-');
var newdate = parts[1]+'-'+parts[2]+'-'+(parseInt(parts[0], 10)%100);
```